# Opencv resize changing the Pixel value

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, image-resizing, opencv3.0, pixel

While training [PixelNet](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aayushb/pixelNet/), I have tor resize the annotated image(label) that has specific pixel value,before resizing ;the image pixels has specif values(annotated objects) ,`np.unique(image)`  gives `[ 0  7 15]`

However when i resize the image with openCV to fit it to my network definition,the pixel values range changes,where

```
image = cv2.resize(image,(cnn_input_size, cnn_input_size),cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

`np.unique(bmask)`
 gives 
`[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]`

This is a disaster for training images with annotated label as these values are specify for other classes,i am wondering if this is the expected behavior of OpenCV while resizing.

Comment: what did you expect as a result ?

Comment: @A.Piro to keep the same values of pixels [0,7,15]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (cnn_input_size, cnn_input_size), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

or

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (cnn_input_size, cnn_input_size), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Right now you're using  the value `cv2.INTER_NEAREST` for the parameters `fx` (scale x), and actually using the default interpolation method that is `INTER_LINEAR`.

Comment: i tried both...give the same result..the i added the zero to see if it doesn't do an scaling

Comment: the line with `interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST` should work correctly. not sure about the other actually :)

Comment: it was due to the fact that i didn't specify the right keyword,this was the problem ecv2.INTER_NEAREST for the parameters fx (scale x),

Answer (score 2):

The opencv's function of **Nearest-Neighbor-Interpolation** has bug when the data-type is not **UV8**.
You have to split the data to **UV8** types and resize and merge them as follows.

```
def scale_uint16(img, size):
    img1 = img // 256
    img2 = img % 256
    img1 = cv2.resize(img1.astype('uint8'), size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2.astype('uint8'), size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    img3 = img1.astype('uint16') * 256 + img2.astype('uint16')
    return img3
```